# check record exist mongodb async driver java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-asyc-driver

Im trying to check if record ecist in my single db using mongo async driver but this dosen t seem to work correctly so what is the most efficient way to check record exist using this stack ,

Im doing simple check like :

```
if(collection.find(new document(..)).limit(0)==null)
then insert in database
```

But this dosen t insert any document  in the database  !!

Comment: What exactly is not working? Limit(0) would always return 0 records and you would never get the existing document even if it exists

Comment: @RachitAgrawal i think that the problem is that im using the async driver to get the collection so collection.find(new document(..)).limit(0) do not return a document if he exist but another object  so i think that the  async driver work otherwise and i should think in another solution